# Where is the origin of the Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++17

This piece of code is supposed to go through a column of a vector of this format: -23 ##.###(where '-' is the beginning of the column and the last # is the end), if you're not aware of the concept of a nanogram, the first number says there are 2 hashes, and the second says there are 3 hashes, there is a minimum requirement of at least one dot(.) or one "whitespace" between each set of hashes(blackspaces). All i want this code to do is to check if the hashes correspond to the numbers for the columns first, but for some reason the input vector;

```
\[\["-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"\],\["-","-","-","2","2","1","-","1"\],\["-","-","-","2","1","1","3","
3"\],\["-","3","1","#","#","#",".","#"\],\["-","-","2","#","#",".",".","."\],\["-","-","2",".",".",".","#","#"\],\["-","1","2","#",".",".","#","#"\],\["-","-","5","#","#","#","#","#"\]\]
```

gives the "segmentation fault" error and codesignal's IDE doesn't much more detail than that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool countSharpsVertically(vector<vector<string>> & referenceVectorOfVectorStrings, int column, int distance) {
    for (int i{}, j{distance}; j<referenceVectorOfVectorStrings.size()/*i < distance*/; i++) {
        while (referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[i][column]=="-") // might want to check if there are no numbers idk how annoying these edge cases are going to be
        i++;
        // cout << (referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[j][column])<< " ";j++;
        while (referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[j][column]==".")j++;
        
        for ( int spaces{}; spaces<stoi(referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[i][column]); j++, spaces++){
            if (referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[j][column]!="#")return false;
        }
        if (referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[j][column]!=".")return false;
        if (i<distance-1&&j>=referenceVectorOfVectorStrings.size())return 0;
        // cout << referenceVectorOfVectorStrings[j++][column] << " ";
    }
        cout << endl;
    return true;
}
bool solution(int size, vector<vector<string>> nonogramField) {
    int distance=(size + 1) / 2;
    //check down
    // cout << distance;
    for (int i{distance}; i < nonogramField.size(); i++ ) {
        if (!countSharpsVertically(nonogramField, i, distance)) return 0;
    }
    //check left
    return true;
}
int main() {
    vector<vector<string>> nonogramField = {{"-","-","-","-","-","-","-","-"}, 
 {"-","-","-","2","2","1","-","1"}, 
 {"-","-","-","2","1","1","3","3"}, 
 {"-","3","1","#","#","#",".","#"}, 
 {"-","-","2","#","#",".",".","."}, 
 {"-","-","2",".",".",".","#","#"}, 
 {"-","1","2","#",".",".","#","#"}, 
 {"-","-","5","#","#","#","#","#"}};
    cout << solution(5, nonogramField);
    return 0;
}
```

All my initial suspicions for the origin of the segmentation fault were wrong, please where is the error coming from.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including input causing the issue and debugger output.

Comment: @user17732522 I'm not sure why, but jdoodle doesn't give me the same error, but it seems like there is a problem according to codesignal

Comment: You are accessing the vector out-of-bounds in line 16 of the code, see https://godbolt.org/z/9v4KfTnGj. If you can't see why that happens, run your program line-by-line in a debugger to figure it out.

Comment: Why does the answer always come with a downvote? Thank you for the peace of mind

Comment: I don't know what downvote you are referring to.